# How to setup multiple many-to-many relationships to one table using EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am currently working on a CMS project where we need to track activities of a user as they edit content throughout the backend. Activity such as creating, updating, or deleting content. I have an idea of how I would like to implement this tracking of activity, but I am not able to find a solution of how to reproduce this in code. There is no code yet for this part of the project, but here’s an overview of the components:

Project is in .NET Core 2, DB is MSSQL. And the DbContext is created using the `dotnet ef scaffold` command (DB-first). For now there are three main content types that a user can edit: Events, Articles, and Pages that each have their own table in the DB. My idea to store user activity is in a table called UserActivity and minimally I would like it to look like this:

```
UserActivity
--------------------
userId (int)
activityTypeId (int)
recordId (int)
recordTypeId (int)
date (datetime)
```

The `activityTypeId` is going to map to a UserActivityType table with records such as “Created,” “Updated”, “Deleted.” The `recordTypeId` is going to map to `1 = Article`, `2 = Event`, and `3 = Page`.

I am not sure if I can properly explain my question, but is it possible in EntityFrameworkCore to setup the Event, Article, and Page entities to each have a many-to-many relationship to the UserActivity entity with having the `recordId` column as the foreign key and a value constraint on the recordTypeId column? Is it even possible in MSSQL? To make this question clearer, here’s some example entries.

Let’s say I have an Article record of ID x, an Event record of ID y, and a Page record of ID z.
So some example records in the UserActivity table would be:

```
userId | activityTypeId | recordId | recordTypeId |       date
--------------------------------------------------------------
    99 |              1 |        x |            1 | 2018-04-15
    97 |              2 |        x |            1 | 2018-04-14
    99 |              1 |        y |            2 | 2018-04-13
    97 |              3 |        y |            2 | 2018-04-12
    99 |              2 |        z |            3 | 2018-04-11
    97 |              2 |        z |            3 | 2018-04-10
```

I know there are other solutions to this problem, such as creating individual activity tables for each of the Article, Event, and Page content types, but ideally I would like to keep track of this in one table, and ideally I would like to use linq select statements that will automatically map to their navigation properties.

Another solution would be to add foreign key columns for each of the content types into the UserActivity table, such as `articleId`, `eventId`, and `pageId`. However, the number of columns will climb with more content types we add and it might become cluttered.

Any feedback and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your sample table shows many to many relationship. And yes, EF will understand it and build classes for you accordingly. I have not used EF core so son't know what all is available there

Comment: Yes, thank you @danish, it is many-to-many and I just updated the post to reflect that. Well I'm glad that it is possible, I just have to research how.

Comment: EF (Core) does not support polymorphic associations, hence the first option is not applicable.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, that's the word I was looking for to describe my problem: Polymorphic associations. Too bad EF Core doesn't support it yet =\